# xlXYScatterLines chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a vba code for the automatic xlXYScatterLines chart generation in excel using a macro. This is my code:

```
Sub GenerateChart()
With Charts.Add 
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
    .HasLegend = True

    Sheets("Members").Activate
    For A = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    Set member = Rows(A).Columns(1)
    If (member.Offset(0, 3)) = (member.Offset(0, 7)) And A <> 1 Then

    X1 = Rows(A).Columns(3)
    X2 = Rows(A).Columns(7)
    Z1 = Rows(A).Columns(5)
    Z2 = Rows(A).Columns(9)
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .XValues = "={" & (X1) & ";" & (X2) & "}"
                .Values = "={" & (Z1) & ";" & (Z2) & "}"
                .Name = member
            End With
    End If
    Next A
End With
End Sub
```

Code works fine when all X and Z are full numbers (without comma's), but code stops when X1, X2, Z1, or Z2 is for example 4,5.. can anyone help to resolve this?

Regards,

Gytis

Comment: Hmmm... works for me.  Can you tell us exactly what error you get when the code stops?  What line?  How about a screen shot of the data Members sheet when the code doesn't work.  Thanks

Comment: I get an error: run-time error 1004, Application defined or Object Defined Error... I get the error in line: .XValues = "={" & (X1) & ";" & (X2) & "}"    when X1 or X2 is a decimal number e.g. 0,75...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the series definitions to be defined by arrays not strings:

```
.XValues = Array(X1, X2)
.Values = Array(Z1, Z2)
```

This might avoid potential issues with regional settings.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error when I enter 4,5 but not if I enter 4.5

Change your decimal deliminator and see if it works.  Your sheet may have come from another country origin that is setup for a different international numbering method for thousands and decimal deliminators.

See this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-the-separator-for-thousands-and-decimals-HP003089676.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring X and Z variables as strings might help. Excel could be converting the commas to periods or vice versa.